# Ansible ec2: "boto required for this module"

Tags: ansible, boto

When I run this simple Ansible playbook:

```
- name: EC2 Test Example
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:
  - name: EC2 Instance
    ec2:
      # Amazon EC2 key pair name
      key_name: my-key-pair
      # Amazon EC2 Security Group
      group: my-security-group
      instance_type: t2.micro
      # Latest from https://wiki.debian.org/Cloud/AmazonEC2Image/Jessie
      image: ami-221ea342
      wait: yes
    register: ec2
```

I run with `venv/bin/ansible-playbook -i localhost, playbook.yml`:

```
PLAY [EC2 Test Example] ********************************************************

TASK [EC2 Instance] ************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "boto required for this module"}
    to retry, use: --limit @/Users/admin/temp/ansec2/playbook.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

So obviously, I have boto installed in the venv that I'm using as well as my default system Python:

```
➜  ansec2 venv/bin/pip list
Package         Version 
--------------- --------
ansible         2.2.1.0 
boto            2.45.0  
boto3           1.4.4   
botocore        1.5.4   
...
```

I've read a few similar posts and I don't see a working solution.

Comment: You don't need this `-i localhost,` hack anymore. Are you sure it's necessary? Ahhh!!! That's the root cause of your problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The root cause of your problem is the `-i localhost,` hack. You don't need to use it anymore in Ansible.

You can just run:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml
```

And with `connection: local` in the play Ansible will use the Python executable set by venv.

---

When you use the `-i localhost,` hack, Ansible calls its default `/usr/bin/python`.

In this case you still can add the `ansible_python_interpreter` parameter to tell Ansible to use this specific environment:

```
ansible-playbook -i localhost, playbook.yml --extra-vars "ansible_python_interpreter=/Users/admin/temp/ansec2/venv/bin/python"
```

But I think you should avoid it and use the first method.

Comment: I absolutely tried `source venv/bin/activate` before my original post. I also put boto in the default system python environment. those are the obvious things to try. neither helped.

Comment: `ansible localhost -a "which python"`

Comment: Also run `ansible-playbook` with `-vvv` and you will see a line `EXEC /bin/sh -c ' .../bin/python ...` - what is the path?

Comment: with venv activated, `ansible localhost -a "which python"` points to venv python `~/temp/ansec2/venv/bin/python`, using `-vvv` with `ansible-playbook` shows `EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python`. So, ansible doesn't seem to use the virtualenv when it is activated. It also isn't using my normal brew installed python at `/usr/local/bin/python`.

Comment: That shouldn't happen with `local` connection, anyway, you can specify `ansible_python_interpreter` and point it to the venv-one.

Comment: from these comments it doesn't seem like this answer worked, yet it was accepted as the correct answer?

Comment: I'm having this same issue, and `ansible-playbook -vvv` is showing the correct virtual environment-- yet i'm still getting that "boto is required" message

Comment: @AndrewFeierman Are you able to resolve it? I am facing the same issue

Comment: The solution I found was to use `ansible-playbook --extra-vars "ansible_python_interpreter=$(which python3)" my_playbook.yml` after installing boto with `python3 -m pip install boto`.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the message was because I was missing boto, although I had boto3. So I did `pip install boto` and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have boto installed for the python interpreter you want to use (as the OP does), then you can tell Ansible to use that python interpreter like so:

```
ansible-playbook --extra-vars "ansible_python_interpreter=/path/to/desired/python" playbook.yml
```

If you want to use `python3`, this can be

```
ansible-playbook --extra-vars "ansible_python_interpreter=$(command -v python3)" playbook.yml
```

If instead you do not have `boto` installed yet, you must install it with pip first before running your playbook. If you want to install `boto` for your `python3` interpreter, you can do so with this command:

```
python3 -m pip install boto
```

If you want to install `boto` for a different python interpreter, use

```
/path/to/desired/python -m pip install boto
```