# Getting error when using Ansible playbook. error message: "msg": "boto required for this module"

Tags: ansible, boto3

I'm trying to execute a playbook for starting an ec2 instance. Have boto3 and python installed on both controlling machine and client node. But it still gives me the error saying:
"msg": "boto required for this module"

Have tried everything suggested here: [Ansible ec2: "boto required for this module"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41774695/ansible-ec2-boto-required-for-this-module). But nada.

Comment: boto and boto3 are different things.

Comment: Pip3 install boto3

Comment: I guess this task most probably runs on localhost. If for whatever reason you run it on a remote host, did you install the requirements there ?

Comment: ohk. thanks guys. have another doubt. i'm workign with python 2.7.3. For this, which version of boto is needed? boto or boto3? 

@error404, I aleady installed boto3 in the remote host. the issue came up inspite of that.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the python `boto` package on the host that is executing the Ansible playbooks.

You can install it via the python package manager

```
$ pip install boto --user
```

If you are using linux you can also install it via the package manager:

```
# RHEL/CentOS
$ sudo yum -y install python-pip

# Fedora
$ sudo dnf -y install python-pip
```

Package dependencies are listed on the Ansible website for each module. For example for the [ec2](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ec2_module.html#ec2-module) module the Ansible host dependencies are:

> python >= 2.6
>   boto

It is worth noting that that boto, botocore, and boto3 are all separate packages.

Comment: But I have already installed boto3 in controlling machine as well as node. That's what I've said in the first line of my question. 
Inspite of being installed, i got the above error. Is the issue related to the version of boto? Like Jack commented above, I'll try installing boto on both machines.